# Facebook messages webhook only works when called from page owner

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks

I have facebook page and app and they are connected. I have verified webhook in app. When i message to this page from account which is owner of page and app, then i get webhook call from facebook. When i message to this page with another account no webhook calls. I have ‘messages’ subscription. What i am missing? How to get webhook calls when anyone messages to this page?

Comment: Did you get all the necessary features and permissions successfully reviewed already? Is the app "live" (if that still applies to yours, the newer app "Access Levels" don't differentiate between dev and live mode.)

Comment: @CBroe i have added person as developer and webhook is working on his messages. in app page there is written that ```To ensure quality and prevent abuse of the platform, all Messenger apps must be submitted for review before they can interact with everyone on Messenger. During development you will be able to send messages to anyone that has been granted either the administrator, developer or tester role for your app.```  so looks like app must be reviewed.

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you need:

1. Make sure the app is "live"
2. Request "Advanced Access" for page_messaging

Advanced access will require you to go through an app review. They ask for some specific details on the functionality of your app.

Read more info on Standard vs Advanced access here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/access-levels/